# Invertibiity of random matrix with correlated entries

Tags: probability, random-matrices, concentration-of-measure

Let $X$ be a random $n \times d$ with independent whose distributions have densities (w.r.t Lesbegue) and let $W$ be a random $d \times k$ marix with independent entries whose distributions also have density. Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and conside the $n \times k$ random matrix $Z$ with entries given by $z_{ij} := f(x_i^\top w_j)$. Finally, let $Q := ZZ^\top$ an $n \times n$ random psd matrix.

> **Question.** If $n < k$, under what conditions on $f$ is $Q$ is nonsingular almost-surely ?

### Observations

- Conditioned on $W$, the rows of $Z$ are independent.

Comment: It seems to me you're asking for too strong a condition (recall that invertible matrices are an open dense set, so if $f$ is continuous and not constant, and if you assume that the $X_{i,j}$, $W_{i,j}$ have a non zero density over $\mathbb{R}$ (let's say they're normal), it's going to be hard for $Q$ to be a.s. singular).
Maybe I'm missing something about the independence of the variables